# How do I generate a random string (of length X, a-z only) in Python?

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python random string generation with upper case letters and digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

How do I generate a String of length X a-z in Python?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
''.join(random.choice(string.lowercase) for x in range(X))
```

Comment: Nice use of generator expressions. But while we're saving memory, might as well use xrange instead of range.

Comment: CytokineStorm, as of Python 3.x, `range()` behaves the same as `xrange()`.

Comment: Just keep in mind that any sequence generated by the random module is *not* cryptographically secure.

Comment: @Federico: Unless you use `random.SystemRandom()`, which should be as cryptographically secure as the OS supports. In modules that need cryptographic randomness, I often do: `import random`, `random = random.SystemRandom()` to replace the module with an instance of the class that provides OS crypto-randomness. `SystemRandom` is the `random.Random` API, with randomness provided by `os.urandom` instead of Mersenne Twister (`os.urandom` is backed by stuff like Window's `CryptGenRandom`, UNIX-like `/dev/urandom`, etc.).

Answer (score 32):

If you want no repetitions:

```
import string, random
''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, X))
```

If you DO want (potential) repetitions:

```
import string, random
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in xrange(X)))
```

That's assuming that by `a-z` you mean "ASCII lowercase characters", otherwise your alphabet might be expressed differently in these expression (e.g., `string.lowercase` for "locale dependent lowercase letters" that may include accented or otherwise decorated lowercase letters depending on your current locale).

Comment: FYI, `string.lowercase` is rarely more than ASCII however you set the locale in my experience. I'm just noting that there is no true variable for "current alphabet".

Comment: Neither of these code samples implies uniqueness. Here is a test: http://pastie.org/8619409

Comment: @Altaisoft: You're misunderstanding how `sample` works. It only draws any given character once, but it's not drawing in order. So `abc` and `cba` would be different outputs. Your test is only valid (would have expected huge numbers of overlaps) if you assume `sample` returns them in the same order they appeared in the original string, but since they can appear in any order, there are `(26+7)! / 7!` options; overlaps won't be common.