# Efficiently generate a 16-character, alphanumeric string

Tags: python, hash, random

I'm looking for a very quick way to generate an alphanumeric unique id for a primary key in a table.

Would something like this work?

```
def genKey():
    hash = hashlib.md5(RANDOM_NUMBER).digest().encode("base64")
    alnum_hash = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9]', "", hash)
    return alnum_hash[:16]
```

What would be a good way to generate random numbers?
If I base it on microtime, I have to account for the possibility of several calls of genKey() at the same time from different instances.

Or is there a better way to do all this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python)

Answer (score 195):

As none of the answers provide you with a random string consisting of characters 0-9, a-z, A-Z: Here is a working solution which will give you one of approx. 62^16 = 4.76724 e+28 keys:

```
import random, string
x = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(16))
print(x)
```

It is also very readable without knowing ASCII codes by heart.

There is an even shorter version since `python 3.6.2`:

```
import random, string
x = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, k=16))
print(x)
```

Comment: The number was actually wrong. I updated it. It is calculated by taking the number of possible characters to the power of the length of the string.

Comment: `ascii_uppercase` or `ascii_lowercase`

Answer (score 64):

You can use this:

```
>>> import random
>>> ''.join(random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for i in range(16))
'E2C6B2E19E4A7777'
```

There is no guarantee that the keys generated will be unique so you should be ready to retry with a new key in the case the original insert fails. Also, you might want to consider using a deterministic algorithm to generate a string from an auto-incremented id instead of using random values, as this will guarantee you uniqueness (but it will also give predictable keys).

Comment: random is not random but pseudo-random according to the documentation. Please use os.urandom instead.

Comment: @prometheus. is `os.urandom` not psuedo-random?

Comment: I was responding to Mark Byers loose usage of the term "random values". ``os.urandom`` is still pseudo-random, but cryptographically secure pseudo-random, which makes it much more suitable for a wide range of use cases compared to ``random``.

Comment: @nikola its doesnt really matter if the keys are only pseudo random, they are used for indexing.

Comment: Perhaps obvious, but 'deterministic' doesn't mean unique, you have to actually check that the algorithm has a very long repetition period. `get_key = lambda n: n % 10` is deterministic, but not unique for long.

Comment: This answer only uses characters A-F whereas the question strongly suggests a-z and A-Z are desired.

Answer (score 45):

In Python 3.6, released in December 2016, the `secrets` module was introduced.

You can now generate a random token this way :

```
import secrets

secrets.token_hex(16)
```

From the Python docs :

> The `secrets` module is used for generating cryptographically strong
>   random numbers suitable for managing data such as passwords, account
>   authentication, security tokens, and related secrets.
>
> In particularly, `secrets` should be used in preference to the default
>   pseudo-random number generator in the `random` module, which is designed
>   for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html

Comment: Docstring: "Return a random text string, in hexadecimal. The string has *nbytes* random bytes, each byte converted to two hex digits. If *nbytes* is ``None`` or not supplied, a reasonable default is used."

Meaning `32 == len(secrets.token_hex(16))`.

Answer (score 42):

Have a look at the [uuid module](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) (Python 2.5+).

A quick example:

```
import uuid
uid = uuid.uuid4()
print(uid.hex)
```

```
df008b2e24f947b1b873c94d8a3f2201
```

Note that the OP asked for a 16-character alphanumeric string, but UUID4 strings are 32 characters long. You should not truncate this string, instead, use the complete 32 characters.

Comment: This is 32 characters, and truncation of Guids is unsafe.

Comment: True (about the truncation). On the other hand: I'd just store 32 characters (unless you have a very specific reason to only store 16).

Comment: @Brian Hi, I need to know why guids is not safe? do you have some reference?

Comment: @AdiyatMubarak: Fundamentally, you don't need a reference. 
 Guids are documented as being unique. 
 Half of a Guid is not documented as being unique. 
 That said, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823 runs through what happens when you truncate one particular GUID algorithm .

Comment: this returns hexadecimal with letters only from a - f.

Answer (score 12):

There's an [official recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#recipes-and-best-practices):

```
import string
import secrets
alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(16))
print(password)
```

This will create output similar to `'STCT3jdDUkppph03'`.

Comment: I think this is the best answer now. More "properly" `random`; denser than `token_hex`.

Answer (score 5):

For random numbers a good source is `os.urandom`:

```
import os
import hashlib
random_data = os.urandom(128)
hashlib.md5(random_data).hexdigest()[:16]
```

Comment: I forgot the so much great urandom function :V and that's nice, better than adding charsets into a string then loop then. Builtin ;)

Comment: this has been mentioned in other answers too, you should not truncate the md5 hash.

Comment: @bman: I'm aware that there a serious issues truncating vertan UUIDs because the randomness is not linearly distributed. vor MD5 this should not be an issue.

Comment: @rlotun You can't just cut out the hash and say it's random. If you do that, the hash function won't be guaranteed to be random.

Answer (score 3):

```
import random
''.join(random.sample(map(chr, range(48, 57) + range(65, 90) + range(97, 122)), 16))
```

Outputs something like:

```
'CDh0geq3NpKtcXfP'
```

Comment: Your solution would omit characters 9, Z and z. Also, sample() chooses every character only once. So it would give you a lot less permutations. This would give you a string of 16 random digits and upper/lower case letters:
`''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for _ in range(6666))`

Answer (score 2):

This value is incremented by 1 on each call (it wraps around).  Deciding where the best place to store the value will depend on how you are using it.  You may find [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx) explanation of interest, as it discusses not only how Guids work but also how to make a smaller one.

The short answer is this:
Use some of those characters as a timestamp and the other characters as a "uniquifier," a value increments by 1 on each call to your uid generator.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer urandom over `secrets.token_hex`, as it samples from a richer character set and hence needs a smaller length to achieve the same entropy.

`os.urandom`, which reads from urandom, is considered secure (see the [relevant answer in a question if urandom is secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3939)). You can then read as much as you like from urandom and produce a random alphanummeric as follows:

```
import math
import os
def random_alphanumeric(str_len: int) -> str:
  rand_len = 3 * (math.ceil(str_len / 3) + 1)
  return base64.b64encode(os.urandom(rand_len), altchars=b'aA').decode('ascii')[:str_len]
```

**NOTE**: The above function is not secure. Since you need a "very quick way to generate an alphanumeric", this function sacrifices performance over security, since the frequencies of `a` and `A` (or whatever characters you choose to replace `+` and `/` with)  will be increased compared to what urandom would give you otherwise.

If you put randomness above  performance, you could do something like:

```
def secure_random_alphanumeric(str_len: int) -> str:
  ret = ''
  while len(ret) < str_len:
    rand_len = 3 * (math.ceil((str_len - len(ret)) / 3) + 2)
    ret += base64.b64encode(os.urandom(rand_len)).decode('ascii').replace('+', '').replace('/', '').replace('=', '')
  return ret[:str_len]
```

Note that chaining `replace` turns out to be faster than sequntially calling it, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27086669/3772123).

Also, in the above, +1 is replaced by +2 when determining  `rand_len`to reduce the number of iterations needed to achieve the requested length. You could even replace by +3 or more to reduce even more the possibility for an iteration, but then you would loose in performance at the chained `replace` calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import secrets


def random_alphanum(length: int) -> str:
    if length == 0:
        return ''
    elif length < 0:
        raise ValueError('negative argument not allowed')
    else:
        text = secrets.token_hex(nbytes=math.ceil(length / 2))
        is_length_even = length % 2 == 0
        return text if is_length_even else text[1:]
```

- **uuid method is inefficient and limited** because uuid only returns 36 characters, and is then truncated.
- **default psuedo-random number generator is not suitable for security or cryptographic applications**, a standard module secrets is available and is designed for these applications.

Answer (score -3):

## Simply use python builtin uuid:

If UUIDs are okay for your purposes use the built in [uuid](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html) package.

### One Line Solution:

```
import uuid
str(uuid.uuid4().get_hex().upper()[0:16])
```

Outputs something like:

```
'40003A9B8C3045CA'
```

Comment: UUID is 32 characters length, by using only characters from 0 to 15, you will get duplicates.

Comment: [GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren't](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823)

Answer (score -3):

simply use python inbuilt **uuid** :

```
import uuid
print uuid.uuid4().hex[:16].upper()
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use the choice function in np.random which chooses the number of characters specified from a list of characters:

```
import numpy as np
chars = np.array(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'))
np_codes = np.random.choice(chars,16)
print(''.join([val for val in np_codes]))
```

this outputs something like the following:
`591FXwW61F4Q57av`