# TypeError for str item assignment

Tags: python, string, random, location, generator

I got the following error :

```
    passwords[k] = passwords[k].strip()
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

but i don't see where it comes from :

```
try:
   list = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') for i in range(random.randint(6,16)))
   passwords = list
   k = 0
   while k < len(passwords):
      passwords[k] = passwords[k].strip()
      k += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "\n [*] Exiting program ..\n"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Don't use the word `list` as a variable name, and can you please fix the formatting in the first block of code?

Comment: You need to tell us what you want the driver (second script) to do

Comment: Please read my new description

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to understand what you want. Have you tried: "from  import random_string"?

I would suggest that you reed a beginners guide to python, https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/
What you need: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

EDIT:
What you want is:

> import random
>
> random.randint(6,16)

Gives a random integer between 6 and 15.

So for you:

> import random
>
> ''.join(random.choice('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') for i in range(random.randint(6,16)))

I'll trust you can manke it into a function if needed.. :-)

Comment: So this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511222/efficiently-generate-a-16-character-alphanumeric-string with a little edit:

>>> import random
>>> ''.join(random.choice('0123456789ABCDEF') for i in range(16))
'E2C6B2E19E4A7777

Comment: btw. I know from random import randint is nicer - use that.. :-)

Comment: I got another problem see my new description please, you seems to know what you're talking about ;)

Comment: So, I can't comment in the question. But two tings

1) If someone want to know what I answer on, please leave the original question, and just make an edit bellow

2) What are you trying to do, and do you know what .strip() do?

Comment: I found you on facebook, could you please accept my request, i really need your help but it's easier on facebook :)

Comment: The whole point of stackoverflow.com is that everyone can benefit of the answers to your and others questions. So lets keep it here.. :-)

Comment: @ Thomas Repsdorph Your above answer didn't work with random.randint() the code works but it only make appears 10 randoms and it starts from a random integer of 1... I would really enjoy to show you the entire script i'm sure you'd have the answer of my problem... Can i send you a PM with stack ?

Comment: So you want more than one random string. A bit annoing I can't se the org. question.. try to run it a few times, it gives diffrent lenghts of strings..

Comment: @ Thomas Repsdorph Yes it gives different lengths but it doesn't go up more than 16 random, i want all the randoms possibilities with all the upper and lower case and numbers !!! :) from 6 length to 15 length : 000000 (6 items) to ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ (15 items) and between all the possibilities with the above chars... I'm desperate...

Comment: Now I understand.. What do you need it for, there are A LOT of combinations, I don't want to do the math right now, but over a million..

Comment: If i tell you why you won't help my anymore... But i need it so please help me to do that. Mercy. I'm desperate...

Comment: I don't like if you try to trick me, or anyone else to do something we don't want to. Try to make some code, and post a question when you have problems..

Comment: I'm not trying to trick you, fine you want my goals ? It's a script for hacking facebook accounts, still want to help me ???

Comment: well, if you can't do this scripy, it makes no sense to try to hack facebook, as they proberly will just ban your IP, if you try all those combinations..

Comment: No i made the attemps invisible in the script i tried on a 4000 passwords wordlist and no blocking whatever could you please tell me the solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a string in that way..

a workaround is to make it to a list, do something with each element and then merge it again..

```
a = 'abc'
b = list(a)
b[0] = b[0].split() # If that's what you want for whatever reason
''.join(b)
```