# Why does Django get_or_create cause this IntegrityError?

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I have a model that has this field on it:
`token = models.CharField(max_length=32, default="", unique=True, null=False, db_index=True)`

In the save() method I set this field to a 32 character random string using this method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if (self.token is None or len(self.token) == 0):
        self.token = random_identifier()
    super(SessionPassthrough, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def random_identifier(n=32):
    """ Generate a random identifier of length n. 

    From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits"""
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits) for x in range(n))
```

However I am getting this error whenever I try to create a new instance of the model:
`IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "wakelytics_sessionpassthrough_token_key"`

To create the instance I call this method:

```
@staticmethod
def for_session(session):
    sp, c = SessionPassthrough.objects.get_or_create(session=session)
    return sp
```

Does get_or_create() call the method's save() function before writing to the database? **Answer: Yes**

I get an IntegrityError whenever I call the method for the first time with a `session`, and continue getting the error for a few minutes. It then returns correctly. What is causing this?

Comment: You *do* know that even a random routine can pick a value that already exists... right?

Comment: I am aware. But every time? and then it stops throwing an error?

Comment: It's random. You don't know *when* it will pick a value not already in your database.

Comment: But in that case it will return without the error _sometimes_, whereas now it reliably fails for the first few times/minutes and then succeeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

From the docs:

The new object will be created roughly according to this algorithm:

```
defaults = kwargs.pop('defaults', {})
params = dict([(k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items() if '__' not in k])
params.update(defaults)
obj = self.model(**params)
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does. Part of its contract is that it *will* return a model that *does* exist, and in order to do that it has to save.

**EDIT:**

You're getting that error because the value already exists in the database.

Comment: If it already exists, wouldnt the get_or_create simply return it? Why raise the error?

Comment: Because `session` is different, hence it's a separate row.