# Most Pythonic Way to Generate Random Strings of Fixed Length From Given Characters

Tags: string, random, python

This is a spin-off of [one of my earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919080/built-in-method-to-generate-random-strings-of-fixed-length-from-given-characters)

Problem statement: Given a number `N` and an arbitrary (but non-empty) `set`/`string`/`list` of characters `E`, return a random string of length `N` made up of the characters in `E`.

What is the most pythonic way of doing this? I can go with `''.join(( random.choice(E) for i in xrange(N) ))`, but I'm looking for a better way of doing this. Is there a built-in function in `random` or perhaps `itertools` that can do this?

Bonus points if:

1. Fewer function calls
2. Fitting into one line
3. Better generalizability to any `N` and `E`
4. Better run-time performance

**PS**: This question is really just me being a Python connoisseur (if I may call myself that) and trying to find elegant and artistic ways of writing code. The reason I mention this is because it looks a little bit like homework and I want to assure the SO community that it is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python random string generation with upper case letters and digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

Comment: are duplicates allowed? ie where N=2 and E='abc', is 'bb' an acceptable string?

Comment: Yes. Duplicates are absolutely allowed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
''.join(random.sample(E*N, N))
```

although that won't work with sets, come to think of it. 
But frankly,

```
''.join(random.choice(E) for i in xrange(N))
```

is already pretty Pythonic -- it's simple, clear, and expressive.

The pythonicness that needs hours of thought is not the true pythonicness.

Answer (score 4):

Your solution already looks pretty good, but here are some alternatives for the sake of completeness:

```
''.join(map(random.choice, [E]*N))
```

Or with itertools:

```
from itertools import repeat
''.join(map(random.choice, repeat(E, N)))
```

If you are on Python 2.x `itertools.imap()` would be more efficient than `map()` since it will not create the full list in memory.

Here is some interesting timing data (tested on Python 2.6):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> t1 = timeit.Timer("''.join(random.choice('abcdefghijkl') for i in xrange(3))", "import random")
>>> t2 = timeit.Timer("''.join(map(random.choice, ['abcdefghijkl']*3))", "import random")
>>> t3 = timeit.Timer("''.join(map(random.choice, repeat('abcdefghijkl', 3)))", "import random; from itertools import repeat")
>>> t4 = timeit.Timer("''.join(random.sample('abcdefghijkl'*3, 3))", "import random")
>>> t1.timeit(1000000)   # (random.choice(E) for i in xrange(N))  - OP
7.0744400024414062
>>> t2.timeit(1000000)   # map(random.choice, [E]*N)              - F.J
4.3570120334625244
>>> t3.timeit(1000000)   # map(random.choice, repeat(E, N))       - F.J
5.9411048889160156
>>> t4.timeit(1000000)   # random.sample(E*N, N)                  - DSM
6.9877378940582275
```

Apparently `map(random.choice, [E]*N)` is the winner, at least for small `E` and `N`.

Comment: Interesting.  I think this data suggests that the OP's solution is the best.  It's the most obvious and within a factor of two of the speed of the best-performing.