# Using Python-playwright, how do I make a screenshot without saving it to disk or using a temporary file?

Tags: python, screenshot, temporary-files, playwright, playwright-python

I want to make a screenshot using Python Playwright and hand that screenshot to a REST API. I found an example [here](https://scrapingant.com/web-browser-automation-with-python-and-playwright/) that makes a screenshot and saves it to a file:

```
from playwright import sync_playwright
with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch()
        page = browser.newPage()
        page.goto('https://scrapingant.com/')
        page.screenshot(path=f'scrapingant-{browser_type.name}.png')
        browser.close()
```

How can I make the screenshot without saving it to disk or using a temporary file and pass it to a REST call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to save the image to a file at all (cmp. [screenshot documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/screenshots/)), but instead can simply store it in a variable, like `img = page.screenshot()`. You can then pass that variable to your REST request. I use the `requests` module in the example below, the POST request is simplified and may require some additional parameters (depending on your API) or for instance different URLs for the different browser types:

```
from playwright import sync_playwright
import requests

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch()
        page = browser.newPage()
        page.goto('https://scrapingant.com/')
        # save screenshot to var
        img = page.screenshot() 
        # pass var directly to your request
        files = {'image': img, 'content-type': 'image/png'}
        requests.post('http://yourresturl.com', files=files)
        browser.close()
```

If you really wanted to save the image to a temporary file for some reason (which, as I understand your use case, is not really necessary), you could e.g. use the [`tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) and create a named temporary file (cmp. [How to use tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11043372/14015737)):

```
from playwright import sync_playwright
import tempfile
import requests

tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.png')

with sync_playwright() as p:
    for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
        browser = browser_type.launch()
        page = browser.newPage()
        page.goto('https://scrapingant.com/')
        # save screenshot to temporary file
        page.screenshot(path=tf.name)
        # send request loading temporary file
        requests.post('http://myresturl.com', {'media': open(tf.name, 'rb')})
        browser.close()        

# close temporary file
tf.close()
```