# How to convert a docx file that is stored in cloud storage to pdf and store it there as well using python cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a docx file stored in cloud storage and I want to convert it to PDF and store it there as well using a python cloud function. Meaning I don't want to download the file, convert it on my local machine and upload it back to storage, so simple stuff like the following code can't be used:

```
from docx import document
from docx2pdf import convert

doc = document()
doc.save('some_path')
convert(docx_path, pdf_path)
```

I tried using io.BytesIO like the following example:

```
import io
from docx import document
from docx2pdf import convert

file_stream = io.BytesIO()
file_stream_pdf = io.BytesIO()
doc = document()
doc.save(file_stream)
file_stream.seek(0)
convert(file_stream, file_stream_pdf)
```

but I am getting the error:

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO.

I know convert receives paths as strings, but I dont know how to use BytesIO in this case.

Is there a simple way to fix what I have done so far or perhaps a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the `BytesIO` object to a temporary file. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11043390/12135518) for more information about `tempfile`.

```
import tempfile

temp_docx_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".docx")

temp_docx_path = temp_docx_file.name  
with open(temp_docx_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(file_stream.read())
```

Then, create another temporary file to handle new `.pdf` file.

```
temp_pdf_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".pdf")
```

Now, convert

```
temp_pdf_path = temp_pdf_file.name  
convert(temp_docx_path, temp_pdf_path)
```

To convert the pdf into the `BytesIO` object, you can do it by:

```
with open(temp_pdf_path, "rb") as f:
    file_stream_pdf = io.BytesIO(f.read())
```

Comment: When I run 
`with open(temp_docx_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(file_stream.read())`
I get the following error: 
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _TemporaryFileWrapper
, do you know how can I fix it? and thank you for your detailed answer @JayPeerachai

Comment: @AmitGoft I have updated the answer, can you try it again? Please make sure that
`temp_docx_path = temp_docx_file.name` before running `with open(temp_docx_path, "wb") as f:     f.write(file_stream.read())`.

Comment: Thank you, now I am getting this error:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'some-path\\tmpgdejwu42.docx' @JayPeerachai

Comment: You need to check the permission if it allows for writing and reading.