# Give permission to Python Flask application running on Apache2 ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu, amazon-s3

I'm running a Flask application on Apache2 server on Ubuntu. The application would take input from a form and save it to a text file. The file exists only for the moment when it's uploaded to S3. After that it's deleted.:

```
            foodforthought = request.form['txtfield']
        with open("filetos3.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(foodforthought)
        file.close()
        s3.Bucket("bucketname").upload_file(Filename = "filetos3.txt", Key = usr+"-"+str(datetime.now()))
        os.remove("filetos3.txt")
```

but the app doesn't have permission to create the file:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'filetos3.txt'
```

I already tried to give permissions to the folder where the app is located with:

```
 sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/webApp/webApp
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Did u check the ownership? try running it from a root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the application is run from a different location. What output do you get from this:

```py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

It's for that directory you need to set permissions. Better yet, use an absolute path. Since the file is temporary, use `tempfile` as [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501262/491233).

```py
foodforthought = request.form['txtfield']

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as fd:
    fd.write(foodforthought)
    fd.flush()

    # Name of file is in the .name attribute.
    s3.Bucket("bucketname").upload_file(Filename = fd.name, Key = usr+"-"+str(datetime.now()))

    # The file is automatically deleted when closed, which is when the leaving the context manager.
```

Some final notes: You don't need to `close` the file, since you use a context manager. Also, avoid setting 777 recursively. The safest way is to set `+wX` in order to only set `execute` bit on directories and `write` bit on everything. Or better yet, be even more specific.