# Python - how to create a random string 8 bytes long?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python random string generation with upper case letters and digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

I need to create a random string that is 8 bytes long in python.

```
rand_string = ?
```

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of [python random string generation with upper case letters and digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits). This question wants a random bytestring, whereas the other one wants a random character string with a limited character set.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
import os
rand_string = os.urandom(8)
```

Would create a random string that is 8 characters long.

Comment: No, it creates a string that is 8 bytes long. "Characters" is a matter of interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

[**`os.urandom`**](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.urandom) provides precisely this interface.

If you want to use the `random` module (for deterministic randomness, or because the platform happens to not implement `os.urandom`), you'll have to construct the function yourself:

```
import random
def randomBytes(n):
    return bytearray(random.getrandbits(8) for i in range(n))
```

In Python 3.x, you can substitute `bytearray` with just `bytes`, but for most purposes, a `bytearray` should behave like a `bytes` object.