# how to set username in user model to a random string

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

views.py

```
def index(request):
    registerform = UserRegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'password' in request.POST:
            registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)    
            if registerform.is_valid():
                result = registerform.save(commit=False)
                result.set_password(request.POST['password'])       
                result.save()
                member.user_id = user.id
                member.member_id = result.id
                member.save() 
          ''''
    return render(request,'index.html',{'registerform': registerform,})
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'is_staff', 'is_active']
```

I am saving the form fields via form.

The username field is included in the form. In the template, I made the username field hidden. How would I create a username with random string while creating the user profile?

Comment: Read the first answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits

Comment: Why not try to set first part(before `@`) of user `Email` as username and if exists bump the suffix by appending an integer until you don't get a unique username? In this way the usernames will be at-least readable as you are taking it from an email.

Comment: @AamirAdnan,great suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this   [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

You can do something like this:

```
import random
import string

def index(request):
    registerform = UserRegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'password' in request.POST:
            registerform = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)    
            if registerform.is_valid():
                username = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(10))
                result = registerform.save(commit=False)
                result.set_password(request.POST['password'])
                result.username = username       
                result.save()
                member.user_id = user.id
                member.member_id = result.id
                member.save() 
          ''''
    return render(request,'index.html',{'registerform': registerform,})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if you can use this.

```
import random
l = list(map(chr, range(97, 123))) 
random.shuffle(l)    
''.join(l)[0:7]
```

Comment: Always printing the same username.