# Generate a random alphanumeric string as a primary key for a model

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I would like a model to generate automatically a random alphanumeric string as its primary key when I create a new instance of it.

example:

```
from django.db import models

class MyTemporaryObject(models.Model):
    id = AutoGenStringField(lenght=16, primary_key=True)
    some_filed = ...
    some_other_field = ...
```

in my mind the key should look something like this "Ay3kJaBdGfcadZdao03293". It's for very temporary use. In case of collision I would like it Django to try a new key.

I was wondering if there was already something out there, or a very simple solution I am not seeing (I am fairly new to python and Django). Otherwise I was thinking to do my own version of `models.AutoField`, would that be the right approach?

I have already found how to generate the key [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits/2257492#2257492), so it's not about the string generation. I would just like to have it work seamlessly with a simple Django service without adding too much complexity to the code.

EDIT:
Possible solution? What do you think?

```
id = models.CharField(unique=True, primary_key=True, default=StringKeyGenerator(), editable=False)
```

with

```
class StringKeyGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, len=16):
        self.lenght = len
    def __call__(self):
        return ''.join(random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for x in range(self.lenght))
```

I came up with it after going through the Django documentation one more time.

Comment: What's the use case for this? A lot of Django features assume an integer primary key, most notably foreign key fields. I won't go so far as to say that this is never a good idea, but I think you might find it simpler to just use the autogenerated string as another field with `unique=True` set.

Comment: It's for a temporary token for an access to a more "hidden" piece of data.The access window is quite short so my need for collision avoidance is quite reduced.

Comment: (off topic) A class with single `__call__` method is called a function and can be written more concisely: `def generate_string(length): ''.join(...)`

Comment: Have you tried a using `default=StringKeyGenerator`, without parentheses? That way, [you pass a callable as the attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default), as in [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) sample code from Django documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would do it without making the field a primary key:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

class MyTemporaryObject(models.Model):
    auto_pseudoid = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True, editable=False, unique=True)
    # add index=True if you plan to look objects up by it
    # blank=True is so you can validate objects before saving - the save method will ensure that it gets a value

    # other fields as desired

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.auto_pseudoid:
            self.auto_pseudoid = generate_random_alphanumeric(16)
            # using your function as above or anything else
        success = False
        failures = 0
        while not success:
            try:
                super(MyTemporaryObject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            except IntegrityError:
                 failures += 1
                 if failures > 5: # or some other arbitrary cutoff point at which things are clearly wrong
                     raise
                 else:
                     # looks like a collision, try another random value
                     self.auto_pseudoid = generate_random_alphanumeric(16)
            else:
                 success = True
```

Two problems that this avoids, compared to using the field as the primary key are that:

1) Django's built in relationship fields require integer keys

2) Django uses the presence of the primary key in the database as a sign that `save` should update an existing record rather than insert a new one. This means if you do get a collision in your primary key field, it'll silently overwrite whatever else used to be in the row.

Comment: So should I keep the original integer primary key and search by the pseudo key? Wouldn't that slow requests down?

Comment: Not if you index it. At least, no more so than using text in place of an integer PK would. Writes will be a little bit slower, since there are two elements to index instead of just one. But I can't see any way to make a randomly generate PK reliably detect collisions without this kind of approach.

Comment: Great, I can live with slower writes.

Answer (score 15):

One of the simplest way to generate unique strings in python is to use `uuid` module. If you want to get alphanumeric output, you can simply use base64 encoding as well:

```
import uuid
import base64
uuid = base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).replace('=', '')
# sample value: 1Ctu77qhTaSSh5soJBJifg
```

You can then put this code in the model's `save` method or define a custom model field using it.

Comment: I would like not to have to use uuid. Sorry should have mentioned it earlier.

Comment: `uuid4` is just a more clever version of random byte generation, that will always return unique results (which is not the case with simple solutions like `''.join(...)`).

Comment: +1 Great trick there. But the @PeterDeGlopper answered all my issues, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is not alphanumeric: `R0oX1ebxQpepGQ/JQsGpNw`, `uCRmokb7QFC+zQCs1hBqNA`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

The if statement below is to make sure that the model is update able.

Without the if statement you'll update the id field everytime you resave the model, hence creating a new model everytime

```
from uuid import uuid4
from django.db import IntegrityError

class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id:
            super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            return

        unique = False
        while not unique:
            try:
                self.id = uuid4().hex
                super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            except IntegrityError:
                self.id = uuid4().hex
            else:
                unique = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below uses the `secrets` library that comes with Python, handles id collisions, and continues to pass integrity errors when there isn't an id collision.

example of the ids `0TCKybG1qgAhRuEN` , `yJariA4QN42E9aLf` , `AZOMrzlkJ-RKh4dp`

```py
import secrets
from django.db import models, IntegrityError

class Test(models.Model):
    pk = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        unique = False
        while not unique:
            try:
                self.pk = secrets.token_urlsafe(12)
                super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            except IntegrityError as e :
                # keep raising the exception if it's not id collision error
                if not 'pk' in e.args[0]:
                    unique = True
                    raise e  
            else:
                unique = True
```