# Sequenced string PK's in python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, sequences

i'm looking for optimal string sequence generator that could be used as user id generator. As far as i get it should implement following features:

- Length is restricted to 8 characters.
- Consists from latin symbols and digits
- Public and thus should be obfuscated

For now i came up with following algorithm:

```
def idgen(begin, end):
    assert type(begin) is int
    assert type(end) is int
    allowed = reduce(
        lambda L, ri: L + map(chr, range(ord(ri[0]), ord(ri[1]) + 1)),
        (('a', 'z'), ('0', '9')), list()
    )
    shift = lambda c, i: allowed[(allowed.index(c) + i) % len(allowed)]
    for cur in xrange(begin, end):
        cur = str(cur).zfill(8)
        cur = izip(xrange(0, len(cur)), iter(cur))
        cur = ''.join([shift(c, i) for i, c in cur])
        yield cur
```

But it would give pretty similar ids, 0-100 example:
'01234567', '01234568', '01234569', '0123456a' etc.

So what are best practices? How, i suppose url shorteners should use some kind of similar algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python random string generation with upper case letters and digits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

Comment: @goncalopp it shouldn't be random, random means collision chance, and i want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need "obfuscated" ids, you want something that *looks* random, but isn't. Fortunately, almost all computer generated randomness [fulfills this criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness), including the one generated by the `random` python module.

You can generate a fixed sequence of numbers by settings the PRNG seed, like so:

```
import random
import string

valid_characters= string.lowercase+string.digits

def get_random_id():
    return ''.join(random.choice(valid_characters) for x in range(8))

random.seed(0)
for x in range(10):
    print get_random_id()
```

This will always print the same sequence of 10 "random" ids.

You probably want to generate ids *on demand*, instead of all at once. To do so, you need persist the PRNG state:

```
random.setstate( get_persisted() )
get_random_id()
persist( random.getstate )
#repeat ad infinitum
```

This is somewhat expensive, so you'll want to generate a couple of random ids at once, and keep them on a queue. You could also use `random.jumpahead`, but I suggest you try both techniques and see which one is faster.

Avoiding collisions for this task is not trivial. Even using hash functions will not save you from collisions.

The `random` module's PRNG [has a period of `2**19937-1`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html). You need a period of at least `(26+10)**8`, which is about `2**42`. However, the fact that the period you need is lower than the period of the PRNG does not guarantee that there will be no collisions, because the size of your output (8 bytes, or 64 bits) may not match the output size of the PRNG. Also, depending on the particular implementation of `choice`, it's possible that, even if the sizes matched, the PRNG simply advances the PRNG on each call.

You *could* try to iterate over the keyspace, checking if something repeats:

```
random.seed(0)
space=len(valid_characters)**8
found=set()
x=0
while x<space:
    id= get_random_id()
    if id in found:
        print "cycle found after",x,"iterations"
    found.update(id)
    if not x% 1000000:
        print "progress:",(float(x)/space)*100,"%"
    x+=1
```

But this will take a long, *long* while.

You could also handcraft a PRNG with the desired period, but it's a bit out of scope on stackoverflow. You could try [the math stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Ultimately, and depending on your purpose, I think your best bet may be simply **keeping track of already generated ids, and skipping repeated ones**.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I was a bit straight forward with random, forgetting about sid capabilities.