# Generate random IPv6 address

Tags: python, random

In Python, what should I do if I want to generate a random string in the form of an IP v6 address?

For example: "ff80::220:16ff:fec9:1", "fe80::232:50ff:fec0:5", "fe20::150:560f:fec4:3" and so on.

Could somebody give me some help?

Comment: [Take a look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits). You should be able to work out how to apply it for your desired format.

Comment: The answer depends on the use case/purpose. Do you just want "something" which might qualify as an IPv6 address, or do you need one from a specific range (just the `fe80::` ones, all `f*` ones, or what). Not all ranges are defined.

Comment: I have to take this method:` ip_v6 = 'fe80::' + random_str() + '1'         `**def random_str():
    import random
    seed = '1234567890abcdef'
    r_string = ''
    for b in range(3):
        for a in range(4):
            r_string = r_string + random.choice(seed)
        r_string = r_string + ':'
    return r_string**

Answer (score 7):

One-line solution:

```py
str(ipaddress.IPv6Address(random.randint(0, 2**128-1)))
```

Or handmade address (but consecutive sections of zeroes are not replaced with a double colon):

```py
':'.join('{:x}'.format(random.randint(0, 2**16 - 1)) for i in range(8))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question to ask you . Could you tell me what the mean of `{:x}` ? I know the mean of `:x` is hexadecimal . But I don't know the mean of `{}`...

Comment: Curly braces `{}` are surround a "replacement field" in a format string for the `str.format()` method. It is something like the `%` symbol in format string used with the `%` string operator (or e.g. `printf()` in C language) - field surrounded by curly braces is replaced with `str.format()` argument. Please compare new [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) with old [String Formatting Operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Answer (score 2):

To generate a random hexadecimal character, you could use this :

```
random.choice('abcdef' + string.digits)
```

Then it should be simple enough to generate your string in the form of an IPv6 address.

You can also find more informations about random string generation here : [Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/python-random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

Answer (score 0):

Adjust functions as needed, this is older python 2.x; but mostly native libraries.

```
import random, struct, socket
from random import getrandbits

print socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, struct.pack('>QQ', getrandbits(64), getrandbits(64)))
```