# Random generate from multiple objects in Python

Tags: python

How can I make the script below generate 1 IPv6 address from each one of the subnets listed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Generate a random IPv6 address for each of the specified subnets
"""

from random import seed, getrandbits
from ipaddress import IPv6Network, IPv6Address

subnet = u'2001:db8:100::/64'
subnet = u'2001:e85:100::/64'
subnet = u'2001:45a:100::/64'

seed()
network = IPv6Network(subnet)
address = IPv6Address(network.network_address + getrandbits(network.max_prefixlen - network.prefixlen))

print(address)
```

Potentially, I'd like to be able to list many different IPv6 subnets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random IPv6 address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016918/generate-random-ipv6-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def generate(subnet):
    network = IPv6Network(subnet)
    address = IPv6Address(network.network_address + getrandbits(network.max_prefixlen - network.prefixlen))
    return address

print(generate(u'2001:db8:100::/64'))
print(generate(u'2001:e85:100::/64'))
print(generate(u'2001:45a:100::/64'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Alex.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Generate a random IPv6 address for each of the specified subnets
"""

from random import seed, getrandbits
from ipaddress import IPv6Network, IPv6Address

subnet = u'2001:db8:100::/64'
subnet = u'2001:e85:100::/64'
subnet = u'2001:45a:100::/64'

def generate(subnet):
    network = IPv6Network(subnet)
    address = IPv6Address(network.network_address + getrandbits(network.max_prefixlen - network.prefixlen))
    return address

print(generate(u'2001:db8:100::/64'))
print(generate(u'2001:e85:100::/64'))
print(generate(u'2001:45a:100::/64'))
```