# Create files of different sizes inside directories recursively in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python script which will traverse through a directory recursively and create files of different sizes inside all of them. So far I have reached here. Well I haven't written any mechanism for creating files with different sizes but I need it. I very well know there's something wrong with the file creation logic I have written. Any help is highly appreciable.

**My code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import uuid

for dirs in os.walk('/home/zarvis'):
  print dirs
  filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
  size = 1000000
  with open(filename, "wb") as f:
    f.write(" " * size)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python Here you find how to generate random strings. By randomize the range you can create random files. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html I think you can randomize what you want with this class.

Comment: Randomizing it is working but I'm unable to create files recursively inside all directories. The problem lies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a fixed `size`. Use [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) to create a random size. Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build the full path to a file.

```
import os
import uuid
import random

for dirs in os.walk("/home/zarvis"):
    d = dirs[0]
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
    size = random.randint(1, 100)
    with open(os.path.join(d, filename), "w") as f:
        f.write(" " * size)
```

Comment: Using my answer to make your working is not really fair... ;)

Comment: This is the problem of what stackoverflow is becoming... people do not want to learn... just working code... So... who cares about explanation... this is working just copy/paste... ;)

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia I completely agree. And even with a language like Python that has excellent documentation and all the tools you need to interactively find out what code does, people are lazy. But has SO ever been any better?

Comment: If you completely agree... then explain the answer instead of simply hunting for reputation.... ;)

Comment: Good point. A first step to write a good answer to a Python question is to link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `os.walk` in the wrong way: with `os.walk` you actually do not change the directory where you are working on. Your script will create files only in the directory where you run it. I do not know exactly what `uuid.uuid4()` does, but probably a solution could be to replace `filename` with

```
filename = os.path.join(dirs[0], str(uuid.uuid4())
```

You need the `[0]` because `os.walk` return a list where the first argument is the current directory where the command is "walking". Try to print the output of `os.walk` once to get a feeling with it.

**EDIT:**

Replaced the `+` with `os.path.join` after comment from @LutzHorn

Comment: `os.path.join` should be used instead of `+`.

Comment: Right on the `os.path.join`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os,uuid,random
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/zarvis/"):
    filename = str(uuid.uuid4())
    size = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    with open(os.path.join(root, filename), "wb") as f:
        f.write(b" " * size)
```