# How to create a varying variable name in python

Tags: python

How can I create varying variable name?

like i am iterating in a loop say from 0 to 100.

I need to create  different variable in each iteration and assign some values to it. an example

```
for i in range(0,100):
   'var'+i=i
```

Doesnot seems valid. I want to create variables in each iteration like var0,var1 etc and should be able to access it with that names. Can some one suggest me a solution

Comment: Read about list datastructure in Python.

Comment: It is possible but it doesn't make sense. use [exec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).

Comment: You should look into [python lists](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists)

Comment: create random strings...follow..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate but you should use eval or exec for this

Comment: @AntonvBR: I think exec will be more useful. but yeah certainly the duplicate.

Comment: You should use a container like a `dict` or a `list`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve this, you can try something like this:

```
for x in range(0, 9):
    globals()['var%s' % x] = x

print var5
```

The globals() function produces a list-like series of values, which can be indexed using the typical `l[i]` syntax.

`"var%s" % x` uses the `%s` syntax to create a template that allows you to populate the `var` string with various values.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a strong reason to create multiple variables on the fly, it is normally in these situations to put things in a list of some sort,
or a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'var{}'.format(i):i for i in range(1,101)}
```

Now access values with:

```
mydict["var1"] # returns 1
mydict.get("var1") # returns 1
mydict.get("var101") # returns None
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like your Idea but yeah you can do it in python:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    exec('var{i} = {i}'.format(i=i))
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend doing this using varying variable names. Instead, you could put everything into a list and you would still be able to access each value independently. For example, you could do:

```
var = []
for i in range(100):
    var.append(i)
```

Then you can access any element from that list like so:

```
var[33]
```

This would return the number 33.

If you really did want each to be its own variable, you could use `exec` as others have noted.

Answer (score 1):

You should better use dictionary for this:

```
var_dict = {
    'var'+str(i): i
        for i in range(10)
}
var_dict['var0']
```