# ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

Tags: python, generator

I have the following generator:

```
import random
import string

def random_string_generator(size = 10, chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):

    return "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

When I use interactive mode to inspect the generator, I get the following:

```
In [30]: random_string_generator()
Out[30]: '6v0vhljxac'
```

However, I do not understand how it works.

From what I've found so far:

1. `_` has no special meaning in the grammar of Python
2. `_` isn't in the `chars` `list`
3. The generator works like `(expression(x) for x in iterator)`

I have tried to further decompose the code in interactive mode and this is what I've found:

```
In [38]: chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits

In [39]: size=10

In [40]: (random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
Out[40]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x10bc6b258>

In [41]: list( (random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    ...: )
Out[41]: ['6', 'v', '3', 'd', 'm', 'c', 'h', '1', 'v', 'n']
```

So my question is how does the `random.choice(chars)` portion of the generator communicate with the iterative part `for _ in range(size)` when they have no apparent connection to each other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python/2257449#2257449

Comment: Basically, you're doing `random.choice` `size` times.  Since you don't care about which iteration you're on at any time, you don't need to keep track of that value in a variable.  `_` is the conventional way of representing a value that you're "dumping"

Comment: `_` is just like any other variable. Replace it with `x` and look at the generator expression again. It is only conventionally used as a way of saying "we don't actually use this value" when you need to assign to something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just calling `random.choice(chars)` `size` many times. The `_` is just being used as a syntactic loop control variable but nothing is done with the `int` values it holds. It's comparable to a loop like the following:

```
for i in range(3):

    print("Spam, ham, and eggs.")
```

Which prints the following:

```
Spam, ham, and eggs.
Spam, ham, and eggs.
Spam, ham, and eggs.
```

In this example, the loop body never implements `i` but it still executes three times as the loop iterates through `range(3)`.

Conventionally, underscores are often used as variable names when we don't care about the value held by a particular variable, such as a loop control variable or one or more values returned by a function with multiple return values. As an example of the latter:

```
def split_name(name):

    first_name, middle_name, last_name = name.split()

    return first_name, middle_name, last_name

_, _, surname = split_name("John R. Doe")

print(surname)
```

In this case, the `split_name()` function returns three values: A first name, middle name, and last name. However, the programmer might hypothetically only be interested in the third return value of the example function, so they might use `_` to catch the first two returned values and use `surname` to collect the value they are actually interested in.

Answer (score 1):

`[a for a in range(10)]` will produce `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` so that this syntax produce list.

`[1 for _ in range(2)]` will produce `[1, 1]` so that `1` is added 2 times in to row.

`[random for _ in range(10)]` will be produce 10 random variable.

`str.join(list)` is just a method of string that joins list elements into a string.