# Pandas: Treat NaN as Unseen Value in One-Hot Encoding

Tags: python, pandas

I have a training set that I'm using to build some machine learning models and I need to set up some code to predict on a test set (that I don't have access to).

For instance, if I have a DataFrame, `train`:

```
    car
0   Audi
1   BMW
2   Mazda
```

I can use `pd.get_dummies` to get:

```
   car_Audi car_BMW car_Mazda
0      1       0       0
1      0       1       0
2      0       0       1
```

Call this resulting DataFrame, `train_encoded`

Now, suppose my `test` DataFrame looks like:

```
    car
0   Mercedes
```

I can use:

```
pd.get_dummies(test).reindex(columns=train_encoded.columns)
```

to get:

```
   car_Audi car_BMW car_Mazda
0      0       0       0
```

How can I treat `NaN`s the same as an unseen value for my `car` column?  That is, if I encounter `NaN` in my `car` column in in `test`, I want to get back:

```
   car_Audi car_BMW car_Mazda
0      0       0       0
```

Thanks!

Comment: `df.car=df.car.fillna('NAN');
pd.get_dummies(test).reindex(columns=train_encoded.columns)`

Comment: @Wen Won't I have an extra column in test after getting dummies if test has a NaN in `car` but train doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

If you generated a string `filler`, that does not appear in `df.car`, then, 
slightly modifying Wen's suggestion in the comment (for the case that `'NAN'` is a string in `df.car`), you can use

```
df.car.fillna(filler, inplace=True) 
pd.get_dummies(test).reindex(columns=train_encoded.columns)
```

One way to define `filler`, if you have access to all of `df.car` in advance, is via

```
filler = '_' + ''.join(df.car.unique())
```

because it is at least longer by 1 than the longest string in it. Another way is by [using a random string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python)

```
filler = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10))
```

The probability you have such an item is less than `len(df) / 26 ** 10`.

Comment: If I have no NaNs in my `car` column for my training set but do have NaNs in my `car` column for test set, I'll have an extra column in my one-hot encoded test, right?