# How can I resolve maximum recursion depth error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm generating a random password with a desired length. I want it to have at least 2 uppercase letters, 2 lowercase letters, 2 digits and 2 special characters. I've tried multiple things, but every time I get this recursion depth error. 
Can anybody tell me what I've done wrong?

```
list_lower =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
list_upper = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N', 'O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'] 
list_digit = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
def generatePassword(desiredLength: int) -> str:
    x = 0
    password = ""
    for x in range (desiredLength):
        password = password + chr(random.randint(33,126))
        list(password)
        list_password = list(password)
        times_lower = 0
        times_upper = 0
        times_digit = 0
        times_special = 0
        for character in list_password:
            if character in list_lower:
                times_lower += 1
            elif character in list_upper:
                times_upper += 1
            elif character in list_digit:
                times_digit += 1
            else:
                times_special +=1
        if times_lower >= 2 and times_upper >= 2 and times_digit >= 2 and times_special >= 2:
            return password
        else:
            return generatePassword(desiredLength)

generatePassword(7)
```

I get the error in line 30 which makes the function recursive.

Comment: Why do it recursively at all? This doesn't seem like a natural use-case. Also -- please don't use things like "line 30". Your editor's line numbering is not preserved in your code.

Comment: Your breaking condition is based on randomness. No matter what you do, there will always be a non-zero chance of recurring too many times.

Comment: First, your function's base case is incorrect: when `desiredLength` is 0, the function returns `None` instead of an empty string. Second, the function calls itself with the same value of `desiredLength` (must be `desiredLength-1`).

Comment: shouldn't the `if -else` branch that makes the recursive call be outside the inner for-loop? Otherwise, it will never possibly have those properties you are hoping (because `len(password) == 1`) and thus, it will always make the recursive call. Anyway, just use a `while` loop. No need for recursion.

Comment: @DYZ If I'm reading it correctly, I don't think this is a case of `desiredLength` going towards zero. I think what OP is going for is generating a random string of desired length, and if it's an invalid string, try again. Notice that the `password` variable is not passed to the recurred function call.

Comment: Also, even with a while-loop, there's a better approach. Choose, randomly, 2 characters from every category you require. Then randomly choose a category and a character until you fill up the desired length. Then shuffle.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that seems like the obvious solution to me too

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That is a natural choice, although it does introduce a slight bias towards passwords with more than the requisite number of special characters.

Comment: @JohnColeman yeaah I was thinking about that. I suppose, you could sample from a distribution which "corrects" for the choices you've already hard-coded. Using the new [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) might be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `generatePassword(7)` will never generate a password with 2 of each of 4 distinct categories.

You don't need recursion at all.

```
def generatePassword(desiredLength: int) -> str:
    while True:
        password = ""
        for x in range (desiredLength):
            password = password + chr(random.randint(33,126))
        times_lower = 0
        times_upper = 0
        times_digit = 0
        times_special = 0
        for character in password:
            if character in list_lower:
                times_lower += 1
            elif character in list_upper:
                times_upper += 1
            elif character in list_digit:
                times_digit += 1
            else:
                times_special +=1
        if times_lower >= 2 and times_upper >= 2 and times_digit >= 2 and times_special >= 2:
            return password
        else
            print ("Rejecting ", password)
```

That will loop forever if asked to generate a password of length 7 or less. We can improve that by checking the desired length first

```
if desiredLength < 8:
    raise ArgumentError("Cannot generate passwords shorter than 8 characters")
```

Answer (score 0):

`times_digit` will never be >= 2 because it tests stings (e.g. "2" against the integers in your list, (e.g. 2) change your `list_digit` to

```
list_digit = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]
```

and try again.

By the way this could be done much simpler and doensn't need a recursive function.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are many more problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating passwords, it's important that you generate ones that actually have enough randomness to not be predictable.

[Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python/23728630#23728630)

Has a great breakdown of how to generate a password that's truly random:

```
''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(N))
```

(adding "special characters" and "lowercase characters" omitted to preserve the existing code)

I know that this is a somewhat oblique answer (i.e. it does not answer the question directly), so here's a potential solution if you still need the "it must contain these types of characters" (even though that would actually reduce security):

```
import random
import string
from collections import Counter

def gen(N):
    return ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for _ in range(N))

while True:
    pw = gen(8)
    counts = Counter(pw)
    upper = lower = digit = special = 0
    for (letter, count) in counts.items():
        if (letter in string.ascii_lowercase):
            lower += 1
        elif (letter in string.ascii_uppercase):
            upper += 1
        elif (letter in string.digits):
            digit += 1
        else:
            special += 1
            pass
    if (lower > 1 and upper > 1 and digit > 1 and special > 1):
        print("password is {}".format(pw))
        break
    print("failed password: {}".format(pw))
```