# If in List vs For loop (performance)

Tags: python, performance

I am curious to know what is faster in Python

Say I have a list

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

I have two ways of checking if an item is in the list.

```
if item in myList:
    # doSomthing()
```

or

```
for element in myList:
    if element == item:
        # doSomething()
```

I know that the first method is more "pythonic" but in terms of performance is there a difference?

Comment: The way you've written it the first is faster in all but the degenerate case: there's no `break` in your `for` loop. The loop also has to create a binding (`element`) that the first version doesn't.

Comment: I didn't add a `break` on purpose, obviously I can add one. With it in is the performance the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing in jupyter notebook, the first option is significantly faster for a string search:

Setup (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python)):

```
rndm=''.join(choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=100000))
```

Tests:

```
%timeit 'a' in rndm
26.2 µs ± 485 ns per loop

%%timeit 
for let in rndm: 
    if let=='a': 
        break
2.42 ms ± 73.7 µs per loop
```

Note: Even if we make a `set()` out of `rndm` and time the search, it still only comes in at `1.14 ms ± 26.9 µs per loop`

Comment: The reason is that the first version runs mainly C code.

Comment: Agreed. Based on the question asked, "Is there a performance difference", I only answered with the "yes"