# List Membership Check vs For Loop Performance

Tags: python, performance

Related to this post: [If in List vs For loop (performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52935060/if-in-list-vs-for-loop-performance)

While timing the execution, test1() is at least twice as slow as test2(). There are fewer lines in test2(). Is it due to this? Besides it and also 'in' being a pythonic way of doing things. Is 'in' mostly more efficient than similar loop structure, and should it be preferred over loops for list and dict checks for performance reasons?

```py
import timeit

a = [n for n in range(1, 1000)]
s = a[len(a) - 1]

def test1():
    for i in a:
        if i == s:
            break

def test2():
    if s in a:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 10000

    print("test1 milli-sec per loop: ", timeit.timeit("test1()",
                                                      setup="from __main__ import test1", number=n) / n * 1000)
    print("test2 milli-sec per loop: ", timeit.timeit("test2()",
                                                      setup="from __main__ import test2", number=n) / n * 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code the two are executing are essentially the exact same, with one major difference: `in` pushes the loop to the C level (assuming CPython), while the second loop is very clearly Python.

C obviously executes faster than Python, giving you the performance difference. In general, if you only want to check for membership (`True` or `False`), use the first option, but if you want to do something more complex, like getting the index (with a loop with `enumerate`) and doing further operations, use the second. For small-ish lists, the time difference is so insignificant that you can freely use either form.