# How to generated code with different or unequal characters in python

Tags: python, generated-code

I'm new to Python. How can I generate this code with a different or unequal character?

I want output like this

- `41PVY02KF#`
- `83#YCF6X15`

  ```
  import random
  import string

  FullChar = CEFLMPRTVWXYK0123456789#
  count = 10
  count = int(count)


  UniqueCode = 0     
  for i in range(count): 
      UniqueCode += random.choice(FullChar)

  print(UniqueCode)
  ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random string generation with upper case letters and digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits)

Comment: @BenT, I think is not a duplication because he wants unique characters from a string, but in that question you make a random choice which implies some characters might repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will have all possible characters in `full_char`, `count` is the length of your `unique_code`, you can use:

```
import random

full_char = 'CEFLMPRTVWXYK0123456789#'
count = 10
unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(full_char, count))
```

This code will generate a code of random characters that are unique from `full_char`.

If you always want to have a `'#'`, you can use the following:

```
import random

full_char = 'CEFLMPRTVWXYK0123456789'
count = 10
unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(full_char, count - 1)) + '#'
unique_code = ''.join(random.sample(unique_code, len(unique_code)))
```