# Hot to make dynamic subplots (optimization of code)

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a figure with subplots. The number of subplots is dynamic and depending on `df.shape`.

This is working but i am not satisfied. I have 3 Questions:

1) Is it possible to optimize the plot part? `if k==b` is lil bit annoying

2) How can I delete the last 3 empty subplots?

3) I was thinking of making a static figure (size=4,4) and opening a new one after the figure is full. How can I realize this?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

import string
import random

# got generator from here: 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits

def id_generator(size=4, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

#%% make random data
labels = []
for i in range(0,27):
    labels.append(id_generator())

mat = np.random.rand(20,27)
df = pd.DataFrame(mat,columns=labels)

#%% plot
k = 0 #go left
l=0 #go down
b = 5 #static number for columns
a = math.ceil(len(labels)/5) #round up for 'go down'
fig, axs = plt.subplots(
    a,b, figsize=(10, 10),sharex=True, constrained_layout=True
)
for j in labels:
    axs[l,k].plot(df[j])
    k+=1
    if k == b:
        k = 0
        l+=1
```

**Edit:**
With help of Chris A the 3 Questions above are solved.

I found out how to change the xlabel,xlim and title. 
Is it possible to change the position of the legend to the top left corner?
Cant find anything in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) and how can i hand over a list with ylabels?

```
df.index.name = 'xlabel'
fig = df.plot(subplots=True, title= 'Make title',y=labels,layout=(-1, 5), figsize=(10, 10),grid=True,xlim=[0,20]) #xticks=[0,5,10,15,20]
```

Comment: You could try `layout` argument of `DataFrame.plot` method. You can pass in `-1` for one of the dimensions and it will work dynamically. eg `df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(-1, 5), figsize=(10, 10))`

Comment: Wow, thank you. One row for all plots :D 
But i need also to set the labels ticks and everything. Maybe i will need to use matplotlib to handle the layout.

Comment: How are you altering ticklabels?

Comment: Havent add them in the miniexample. I will check your command and try it :) Thank you