# Trying to make a machine that makes random words and number but the sep do not work, python

Tags: python

Hey i cant get the sep="" to work could someone help?

```
import random
import string


def randomString(stringLength=3):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


for i in range(1):
    print(randomString(3), (random.randint(0, 99)), (randomString(3)), sep='')
```

Comment: What output do you want? Do you want string and number in same line or different line?

Comment: I want it so it gives me 3 words 2 numbers and 3 words, and then they need to be together but, the sep="" dosent work for me

Comment: It works fine for me. Output: `mdo82yqr` BTW, which Python version are you using?

Comment: Im using 2.7.18

Comment: If you are on Python 2.7, then please note that `end` and `sep` are only for Python 3.x or higher versions.

Comment: Oh okay ty ill download that version then :)

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5 working fine

```
import random
import string


def randomString(stringLength=3):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


for i in range(1):
    print(randomString(3), (random.randint(0, 99)), (randomString(3)),sep="",end="")
```

you can also use like this

```
import random
import string


def randomString(stringLength=3):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))


for i in range(1):
  print(randomString(3)+str(random.randint(0, 99))+(randomString(3)))
```