# How come this List Comprehension does not produce the same results as this for/in loop?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, jupyter-lab, for-in-loop

Generating a List of random strings, then using a for/in loop and also a List Comprehension expresison to fund the longest string and the length of that string.

Both techniques compute the max length correctly, but sometimes the for/in loop finds the same longest word as the List Comprehension, sometimes not. Why? What's the logic error?

```
import random
import string
def cobble_large_dataset(dataset_number_of_elements):
    '''
    Build a list of Lists, each List is a String of a random sequence of 1-10 characters
    '''
    myList = []         # Empty List   
    for i in range(0,dataset_number_of_elements):
        string_length = random.randint(1, 10)
        tmp = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=string_length))  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits
        tmp = [tmp]
        #print(tmp)
        myList.extend([tmp])
    return myList    

def list_comprehension_test(wordsList):
    '''
    Process a List of Lists using List Comprehension. 
    Each List in the List of Lists is a single String
    '''
    start_time = time.time()
   
    maximumWordLength, longest_word = max([(len(x[0]), x[0]) for x in wordsList]) # This works because x is a List of strings
    return ((time.time() - start_time), longest_word, maximumWordLength)

def brute_force_test(wordsList):
    '''
    Process a List of Lists using a brute-force for/in loop. 
    Each List in the List of Lists is a single String    
    '''
    start_time = time.time()
    maximumWordLength = 0
    for word in wordsList:
        tmp = word[0]
        #print(tmp)
        if (len(tmp) >= maximumWordLength):
            maximumWordLength = len(tmp)
            longest_word = tmp
            #print(tmp)
            #print(longest_word + " : " + str(maximumWordLength))
    return ((time.time() - start_time), longest_word, maximumWordLength)

import time
start_time = time.time()
dataset = cobble_large_dataset(100)
print (str(len(dataset)) + ' Strings generated in ' + str((time.time() - start_time)) + ' seconds.')

# Let's see if both techniques produce the same results:
result_brute_force = brute_force_test(dataset)
print('Results from Brute Force = ' + result_brute_force[1] + ', ' + str(result_brute_force[2]) + ' characters' )
result_list_comprehension = list_comprehension_test(dataset)
print('Results from List Comprehension = ' + result_list_comprehension[1] + ', ' + str(result_list_comprehension[2]) + ' characters' )
if (result_list_comprehension[1] == result_brute_force[1]):
    print("Techniques produced the same results.")
else:
    print("Techniques DID NOT PRODUCE the same results
```

Comment: fyi, `myList.append(tmp)` is the same as `myList.extend([tmp])` and is more natural and clear.  You do just want to append `tmp` to the list, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your list comprehension case, you want to tell `max` to just operate on the first item in each of the pairs of values in the list.  This is the equivalent of what the for-loop case is doing, since it only considers the length of each string. So you want:

```
maximumWordLength, longest_word = max(
    [(len(x[0]), x[0]) for x in wordsList],
    key = lambda x: x[0])  # This works because x is a List of strings
```

As others have already pointed out, you also want to change the `>=` comparison in the brute-force case to `>`.  If you make these two changes, you will get the same result from your two methods.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now that max() considers the arguments in left-to-right order in order to break ties. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a list of tuples to `max`, with no `key` function, so `max` is comparing tuples, not just lengths. When the lengths tie, tuple comparison moves on to comparing the second elements, the strings themselves, so the max in case of a length tie is the string that compares greatest (by lexicographic code point comparison).

In contrast, in case of a length tie, your loop picks whichever candidate appears last. (If you had used `>` instead of `>=` in `if (len(tmp) >= maximumWordLength):`, it would pick the first candidate.)

(Also, that's some weird stuff you're doing with `tmp`. The 1-element lists you're building are pointless - `cobble_large_dataset` should just return a flat list of strings.)

Comment: I think `max` looks at the second value in the case of ties. So it doesn't pick the first, but the "biggest" by the second value, i.e. biggest lexicographically.

Comment: I already tried changing the comparison to > rather than >= and the inconsistent results don't change.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych: Ah, right, forgot this code is doing straight tuple comparison instead of using a `key` function. Been up too long. Fixed now.