# I get TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k' , when using python random.choice

Tags: python, random

I want to generate a random string of length n, on a given alphabet.

```py
import random
alphabet = "ACTG"
n= 10
# print(''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for x in range(n)) ) # work fine

print(''.join(random.choice(alphabet, k=n))) # doesn't work
```

The error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'k'
```

Comment: Where are you confused?  The documentation for `choice` shows no argument `k`.  The error message tells you that's the problem.

Comment: @Prune , following the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2257449/3429103), it give th both solution `''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for x in range(n))`  and also, for python 3.6, we can use a more **concise** code `''.join(random.choices(alphabet, k=n))`. So without noticing the *s* at the `random.choices` I thought it is the same method but with different parameters. So after that I thought it was a good idea to share this for others, in case they get in the same confusion as I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct method is **choices** with **s**, so use **`random.choices`**.
The mistake come from the two function that have similar names. The first is **`random.choices`** with **s**, and the second one is **`random.choice`** without **s**.

```py
import random
alphabet = "ACTG"
n= 10

# print(''.join(random.choice(alphabet, k=n))) # gives an error
print(''.join(random.choices(alphabet, k=n))) # the correct method, work fine
```